No Wi-Fi adapter found MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7902
I have just installed in my new ASUS Vivobook Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. While with original Windows 11 it recognized my Wi-Fi, it does not with Ubuntu (No Wi-Fi adapter found). I run the lshw -C network command:
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fcc00000-fccfffff memory:fcd00000-fcd07fff

Can someone help?
